# GOOGLE SHEETS : Testing for cell color and outputting value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am keeping a spreadsheet full of dates. I have setup conditional formatting for these dates to be one of either two colors (Red or Green). What i now need is a formula for a script that i can run to detect which cells are green (Within a specified range) and to output a number value (how many green cells) to a specified cell.

In a nut shell. I have 3 different sets of dates. I would like a script to run that will read a specified range of cells and output a number value to a specified cell which will tell me how many green cells there are (within the range specified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counting Colors**

```
function cellColors() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var bgA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var cObj={cA:[]};
  for(var i=0;i<bgA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<bgA[i].length;j++) {
      if(cObj.hasOwnProperty(bgA[i][j])) {
        cObj[bgA[i][j]]+=1;
      }else{
        cObj[bgA[i][j]]=1;
        cObj.cA.push(bgA[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(cObj);
  sh.getRange(1,26,1,100).clearContent().setBackground('#ffffff');//clear output area
  var org=sh.getRange(1,26,1,cObj.cA.length);//output range
  var ocA=[];
  var onA=[];
for(var i=0;i<cObj.cA.length;i++) {
  ocA.push(cObj.cA[i]);
  onA.push(cObj[cObj.cA[i]]);
}
  org.setBackgrounds([ocA]);
  org.setValues([onA]);                
}
```

Output is sent to Z1 and the following cells in that row indicate the color and number of each color in the same cell.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

> The output is in the upper right hand corner

If you only want to count certain colors then here's a modification.

```
function cellColors2(colors) {
  var colors=colors || '#008000';//This controls what color you want to limit yourself to counting are default '#008000' is green - '#008000,#ffffff' is green and white
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var bgA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var cObj={cA:[]};
  if(!colors) {
  for(var i=0;i<bgA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<bgA[i].length;j++) {
      if(cObj.hasOwnProperty(bgA[i][j])) {
        cObj[bgA[i][j]]+=1;
      }else{
        cObj[bgA[i][j]]=1;
        cObj.cA.push(bgA[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  }else{
    var colorA=colors.split(',');
    for(var i=0;i<colorA.length;i++) {
      cObj[colorA[i]]=0
      cObj.cA.push(colorA[i]);
    }
    for(var i=0;i<bgA.length;i++) {
      for(var j=0;j<bgA[i].length;j++) {
        if(cObj.hasOwnProperty(bgA[i][j])) {
          cObj[bgA[i][j]]+=1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(cObj);
  sh.getRange(1,26,2,100).clearContent().setBackground('#ffffff');//this controls what range gets clears each time
  var org=sh.getRange(1,26,1,cObj.cA.length);//this control where the display is set
  var ocA=[];
  var onA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<cObj.cA.length;i++) {
    ocA.push(cObj.cA[i]);
    onA.push(cObj[cObj.cA[i]]);
  }
  org.setBackgrounds([ocA]);
  org.setValues([onA]);
  org.offset(1,0).setValues([ocA])
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have grasped what i wanted perfectly. Thank you very much. Just a couple of edits though. I only need an output of 1 color (green). And (Im not very script savy) Could you highlight which parts i can modify to set my specific grid and which part to change the output cell

Comment: Which green do you want?

Comment: Do you want to remove report for white? (i.e. '#ffffff')

Comment: I set it up to count just green in the bottom version.  You can change the color set by changing the default color string.